# how to setup a django modelform with ranges of dates and times

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a submission `modelForm` set up with a submission model that consists of mostly char fields but I want to add a datetime field that has a datetime start and datetime end.  What is the best way to set something like this up?

```
|------ char data 1
|------ char data 2
|
F__ range --- start datetime |
O   data  --- end datetime   |   +?
R
M------ char data 3
| 
|    ...
|
```

Each rangedata will go with one specific submission of the form, so there could be multiple start and end datetimes.

I have tried setting up a separate datetime range model that has a foreign key to relate back to the submission model that will take in two datetimes but I am unsure of how to change the submission form form to now include the datetime range model. Would `inlineformset_factory` be the correct way forward? Or just the `formset_factory` from forms? Do I also need a separate datetime range form to be rendered within the parent submission form? I ideally would like an array of start/end tuples in the rangedata column in my database but I'm not sure if that's possible. A separate database linked to each submission could also work, but each entry should be a tuple of start/end datetimes instead of two separate lists of just all start and end times, because I think it would probably be too difficult/not worth it to guess which start and end datetime would go together? The postgres `DateTimeRangeField` was almost exactly what I want, except I kept getting list has no method strip() and I wasn't sure how to separate the datetimes out into a useable format.